# How to solve xbuild '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile344' issue on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, portable-class-library, xbuild

I tried to compile [my project](https://github.com/ziyasal/InfluxDB.Net) with following instructions so I get following error.

My script;

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete  
mozroots --import --sync 
mkdir gthb  
cd gthb/  
git clone https://github.com/ziyasal/InfluxDB.Net.git
cd InfluxDB.Net/   
mono .nuget/NuGet.exe install NUnit.Runners 
mono .nuget/NuGet.exe restore InfluxDB.Net.sln 
xbuild
```

Output;

XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 3.2.8.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 01/06/2015 18:31:01.

---

Project "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.sln" (default target(s)):
        Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
                Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
        Target Build:
                Project "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.csproj" (default target(s)):
                        Target RestorePackages:
                                Executing: mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/.nuget/NuGet.exe" install "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net/packages.config" -source 
""   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/"
                                Restoring NuGet packages...
                                To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download 
missing packages'.
                        Target PrepareForBuild:
                                Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU
                                Created directory "bin/Debug/"
                                Created directory "obj/Debug/"
                        Target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths:
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile344'. Framework ass
embly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior.
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : PCL Reference Assemblies not installed.
                        Task "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" execution -- FAILED
                        Done building target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in project "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.csproj".-- FAILED
                Done building project "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.csproj".-- FAILED
        Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "Build" in project "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.sln".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.

Warnings:

/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets (GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) ->

```
    /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile344'. Frame
```

work assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior.

Errors:

/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/ziyasal/gthb/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net/InfluxDB.Net.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets (GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) ->

```
    /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : PCL Reference Assemblies not installed.

     1 Warning(s)
     1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.8459340

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I found solution (workaround) for this. I copied .NETPortable (**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable**)  folder from my Win box to Linux box (**/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/**).

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
A7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  mono-devel
sudo apt-get install  mono-complete
sudo apt-get install  referenceassemblies-pcl

#Import the root certificates using the mozroots tool
mozroots --import --sync

#UPDATE: referenceassemblies-pcl package installs required profiles!
#####DEPRECATED#######
#I uploaded .NET Portable folder to temporary place.
#sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
#wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33940399/NETPortable.7z

#Override existing
#sudo 7z x NETPortable.7z -o/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/ -aoa
#####DEPRECATED#######
mono .nuget/NuGet.exe restore InfluxDB.Net.sln

xbuild

mono packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.4/tools/nunit-console.exe 
InfluxDB.Net.Tests/bin/Debug/InfluxDB.Net.Tests.dll
```

It compiles well now!

Comment: Can you file a bug on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ for the referenceassemblies-pcl not installing the PCL profiles? I would have expected the referenceassemblies-pcl to install everything you need, but I could be wrong.

Comment: OK I see what the problem is. The referenceassemblies-pcl is based on what Microsoft released and not what Visual Studio installs (nor what is available with Mono on the Mac). The referenceassemblies-pcl is missing profile 344 which is the profile you are using.

Comment: @MattWard Jo just pushed an update of the referenceassemblies-pcl package that includes Profile344.

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger - Thanks. I was just about to email Jo about it :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you do not have the Portable Class Library reference assemblies installed.

I would look at using a later version of Mono 3.10 and installing the referenceassemblies-pcl package. There are more detailed instructions on the [Mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) about using Mono on Linux.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: I have installed referenceassemblies-pcl package but I still getting error.